# Community bot bumping many old "unanswered" questions that actually do have answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed the ["Community" bot](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/-1/) bumping a lot of older question threads to the top of the queue.  If you go into the activity history, the "bump" action has the comment text:

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

Many (most?) of these posts share the following characteristics:

- Question written by low-activity, low-reputation user
- Has answers
- No answers are marked as "accepted"
- Highly unlikely that the OP will ever mark any answer as "accepted"

Is there any way that community members (presumably moderators) could flag or categorize such questions, so the Community user stops bumping them and stops cluttering up the queue with these old and permanently-stale posts?

Should we create a "perma-stale" tag to help categorize and identify posts like this, which are unlikely to ever have an "accepted" answer (due to the OP not returning)?

Is there any way to message the OP, in order to ask them to choose an answer post, or to comment to explain what aspect of their question is still unaddressed?

---

Note that this is similar to, but separate from, the following Meta thread:

- [Accepting an answer to someone else's question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/accepting-an-answer-to-someone-elses-question)

  - I am not suggesting that we try to force an answer post to be marked as "accepted".  Rather, I am trying to come up with ways for the Community bot to stop bumping these perma-stale posts.

Comment: Actually, it happened not too long ago when Snailplane left SE: [What's up with these old questions showing up on the front page?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/whats-up-with-these-old-questions-showing-up-on-the-front-page). This and that one are tragic losses for JLSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/361699), posts that have a non-negative score with no activity within 30 days with at least one non-deleted answer with a score of 0 and no positive scoring answers with no accepted answer are eligible to be bumped.

The points you mentioned in your question were *almost* correct, but if a question only has negatively scored answers or has one positively scored answer, it no longer gets bumped. Therefore, if you want a question to stop being bumped, you can upvote an answer, or if the answers are bad, downvoting them works too.

The point is to get people to look at and review answers that have gone unnoticed, so reviewing these answers will stop it from bumping the post.

Comment: Aha, the voting status appears to be the key.  Thank you for noting that!  The auto-bumping is an easily fixable issue then.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The reason the homepage has been rendered useless over the past few days is because one of the most frequent voters on the site deleted their account, which undid all of his votes, leaving hundreds of questions which previous had a 1-positive-vote answer with only a 0-positive-vote answer. So now the Community bot is aggressively filling the homepage with them even though nothing has changed (the questions still have answers that someone thought was good at some point).

StackExchange should have a solution for this issue, such as not removing all the rep for such a major account deleting, or at least rate-limiting the Community bumps more, but it seems they don't.

Comment: Sheesh, hadn't realized that the user deactivation is what caused this flood of old stuff -- I thought perhaps the Community bot had simply been offline for a while, or that its queue had gotten stuck for some reason.  I agree that the SE devs dropped the ball in this regard, but sadly, I'm learning to have low expectations for them.

Comment: Haha, thankfully someone instead has upvoted some of them for me after that. I agree with you regarding not deleting all his/her votes to the creditworthiness of an answer thanks to his/her efforts. However, if it had been done by only one user, I guess it does not affect the evaluation of an answer so much overall. For sure, It might still depend on the voters’ expertise and knowledge though…

Comment: "*Stack Exchange should have a solution for this issue, such as not removing all the rep for such a major account deleting*" actually, [it has been considered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/241919). However, depending on the situation (which might be related to the suspension), the votes may have to be invalidated.